# How to get users browser history using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having my shopping website and i want to do add of my products using google ad-words.So can any one help me how can i get the browser history for users's searches.Like what type of products users are searching so we can provide add for that to customer.In short i want to access users local storage.
How we can store the users search data into cookies. and when next time user is trying to search that same product than we can show them last search.

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not possible. Accessing the users history would be a giant security problem.

Comment: we can get users local storage history i am sure about this. for example if you search something from shopping sites . and after some time if you open you tube and some other sites those are showing advertisments than you will find results there according to your last search

Comment: This is done serve site with tracking cookies. The search engine is owned by the same company as YouTube. Googles *knows* what you searched for.

Comment: and you have tried what all ready? http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/